# GA - E-commerce not tracking items

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have severe trouble finding the issue in the following javascript code.

Google Analytics is tracking my transactions just fine, but it does not show any products.

This code is taken from the "view sourcecode" at the receipt page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxxx-x']); // I replaced my account no.
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 
_gaq.push(['_set', 'currencyCode', 'DKK']); 

_gaq.push(['_addTrans', 
'28996', 
'xxxxx.xx', // I replaced the domainname with xxxxx.xx
'104.00', 
'20.80', 
'0.00', 
'fredercia', 
'Denmark' 
]); 


_gaq.push(['_addItem', 
'28996', 
'150649', 
'BRAUN ORAL-B ELTANDB&#216;RSTE', 
'99.00', 
'1' 
]); 




_gaq.push(['_addItem', 
'28996', 
'150000', 
'5 dages LOP-salg', 
'5.00', 
'1' 
]); 


_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); 

(function () { 
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
})(); 

</script>
```

Can anyone see the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the `category` parameter to `_addItem` -- see the [Google Docs for _addItem](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addItem).

While the `category` parameter is optional, leaving it out will cause the required `quantity` parameter to be missed.

You can pass an empty string for `category` if you don't have one:

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem', 
'28996', 
'150649', 
'BRAUN ORAL-B ELTANDB&#216;RSTE', 
'',
'99.00', 
'1' 
]);
```